# Multiple method calls

Tags: python-3.x, object, keras

Well I'm trying to decipher a piece of code and it's a part of a larger script, which I've briefly outlined in the following code.

```
class YoloLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, anchors, max_grid, batch_size, warmup_batches, ignore_thresh, 
                grid_scale, obj_scale, noobj_scale, xywh_scale, class_scale, 
                **kwargs):
        //instantiation follows

    def build(self, input_shape):
        //function definition follows

    def call(self, x):
        //function definition follows


loss_yolo_1 = YoloLayer(anchors[12:], 
                        [1*num for num in max_grid], 
                        batch_size, 
                        warmup_batches, 
                        ignore_thresh, 
                        grid_scales[0],
                        obj_scale,
                        noobj_scale,
                        xywh_scale,
                        class_scale)([input_image, pred_yolo_1, true_yolo_1, true_boxes])
```

In this I couldn't fully understand the last line of the code.In the last line as I understand it, with `YoloLayer(something...)` a call to `__init__(something...)` method of the YoloLayer class is made, which would instantiate and return the YoloLayer instance. So far so good, but now my question is, which method is the attached second bracket trying to call?I mean the following bracket.

```
([input_image, pred_yolo_1, true_yolo_1, true_boxes])
```

Comment: `instances are callable if their class has a __call__() method` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=__call__#callable

Comment: thanks but I couldn't understand how this link is useful in my question, I mean can you please elaborate?

Comment: `which method is the attached second bracket trying to call?!` - `__call__` method of `YoloLayer(...)` object.